# Does two activity in the same package belong to the same thread?

Tags: android, android-activity, native-code

I have two activities under the same package (the main activity and another one). Sometimes i need to start the other activity with `startActivityForResult`. I have two questions:

1. Does the two activities belong to the same thread?
2. If i load a native library in the main activity, can i access the native methods from the other activity?

Regarding question 2, suppose there is a native method called `NativeMethod1()`. In the main activity, as usual, i have the following declaration:

```
public native void NativeMethod1();
```

and in the native code i would have a function properly declared (using Java_com_mypackage_myapp_ etc ..). I have added a similar declaration for the other activity, and, in the native library, i added a corresponding method declaration as well. All is working fine, but i fear i am assuming something that it is not always true. This would results in unpredictable crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't add native methods into your `Activity` class. Instead, create a singleton class that you can use from all activities.

Now as far as threading is concerned, yes the UI model for Android is single threaded (aka main thread or UI thread) so all your activities are running on the main thread.

Do not block the UI thread when you are doing long running operations as this will result in an ANR (Activity Not Responding) case, so if you are doing something fancy in your native methods you are better of using an `AsyncTask` or a `Service` or come up with your own background threading model.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think to the singleton class for the C++ wrapper, nice...regarding native computations, i already use AsyncTask and it is working perfectly, even if it is not that fast (i use a native library of mine because of code reuse and because Android will not be the only supported platform).